# Calculate the recurrence use repeated unfolding

Tags: algorithm, math, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

I am trying to calculate T (n) = 2 T (n/2) + n (log n)^2.
Following the step I got:

```
=2^kT(n/2^k)+ nlog2 (n/2^(k-1))+ nlog2 (n/2^(k-2))+…+ n(log (n/2))^2 + n (log2 n)^2
```

when n=2^k I got:

[image: formula]

But I have no idea about how to simplify the summation formula and get  Θ() notation.
Any one can help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hint: the closed-form series solution is quadratic in the index `i`. Expand this to give three series and use the standard formulae for summations of integer powers

Comment: what is the standard formulae for summations of log powers(not integer)?

Comment: If you use the logarithm rules you'll find that you are infact summing over integer powers and not the logarithms themselves, the latter being the "coefficients". I will post an answer shortly

Comment: All right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation you have doesn't look quite right to me. Let's re-derive it:

[image]

... after `m` iterations. Let's assume the stopping condition is `n = 1` (without loss of generality):

[image]

... where we have employed two of the logarithm rules. As you can see the summation is in fact over "free indices" and not the logs themselves. Using the following integer power sums:

[image]

... we get:

[image]

To evaluate the Θ-notation, the highest order term is:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you explain  after m iterations why you delete 2^m*T() ? Can I make n=2^m? For example if  T (n) is a constant for n<=2, can I make 2*n=2^m?

Comment: That's what the "stopping condition" means - there is no more recursion after it is met. You can do it the other way using n=2^m but I think the top-down approach is more intuitive

Comment: Thanks a lot, a question why you delete "2^m*T()" after migration? should it be n*C(C is constant)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "migration"? Typically at the stopping condition the function only returns a constant, which can be ignored anyway.

Comment: Yes, I mean T(n/2^m)can be ignored, but maybe intreprete 2^m to n?

Comment: I find the bottom-up method (n=2^m) to be less satisfactory, as n is not necessarily a power of 2, so your starting value of m is not necessarily integer. But you can do as you wish

Comment: you've derived `T(n) = (2^m)*T(1) + SUM (n log^2 ...)` and then you omitted the `(2^m)*T(1)` altogether. Is T(1) really 0, not 1?

Comment: @willness as I said in a previous comment, T(stopping condition) can be any constant, and as long as the resulting term has lower time complexity than the summation term, it can be ignored completely

Comment: thank you; yes, but only *after* we've derived the sum. Not before. Right?

Comment: @willness I believe this step is intuitive because the previous factors of 2^m are multiplied with an n (log n)^2 term, whereas the final one only with a constant. But in general, yes one must not be too hasty

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_2_example), you will realise that the question you have asked is actually the `2nd` case of `Master Theorem` (Refer to the link above).

So, here `a=2`, `b=2`, and `f(n) = 0[n^(c_crit)(log n)^k]` where `k=2` and c known as `c_crit` = `log a to base b` = `1`.

So, by Master Theorem, `T(n) = 0[(n^c_crit)(log k)^(k+1)]` = `0[n(log n)^3]`

Comment: @flower If you want to have exposure to more such problems, have a look here (http://www.dei.unipd.it/~geppo/DA2/DOCS/recurrences.pdf). Probably most of your doubts will be cleared if you refer to the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do you know standard formulae for summations of log powers(not integer)? because for this one I want to try without master theorem. Just this final step then I can get it.  Just proof the summations is (logn)^3 in this case.

Comment: @flower Which log power do you want! Because generalizing it would be very difficult. For integers, however long and complex it may be, you can still find out. For logarithms, not easy!!